# How to replace two similar HTML elements with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two similar elements to replace:

Replace:

```
    <div class="radio__label content-box__emphasis ">
      <label class="radio__label__primary" for="checkout_payment_gateway_1">
          Payment 1
</label>
</div>
```

with:

```
    <div class="radio__label content-box__emphasis payment-method-wrapper">
      <label class="radio__label__primary" for="checkout_payment_gateway_1">
          <img alt="Payment 1" class="offsite-payment-gateway-logo" src="payment-1.png">
            <span class="visually-hidden">
              Payment 1
            </span>
</label>
</div>
```

And analogously for a Payment 2.

I want to do this without jQuery.

I don't want to add `payment-method-wrapper` to all `<div class="radio__label content-box__emphasis ">` on the site, but only for Payment 1 and Payment 2.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: `What would be the best approach to do this?` What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried simple string replacing for `<div class="radio__label content-box__emphasis ">`, but I don't want to replace all those elements on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moti Korets beat me to it, but here's a more complete solution:

```
function transformLabelContainer(id, imgSrc) {
  const label = document.querySelector(`label[for$=_gateway_${id}]`);
  const labelDiv = label.parentElement;
  labelDiv.className += 'payment-method-wrapper';
  const originalText = label.innerText;
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'visually-hidden';
  span.innerText = originalText;
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.alt = originalText;
  img.className = 'offsite-payment-gateway-logo';
  img.src = imgSrc;
  label.replaceChild(img, label.firstChild);
  label.appendChild(span);
}

const labelsToTransform = [
  {
    id: '1',
    imgSrc: 'payment-1.png'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    imgSrc: 'payment-2.png'
  }
];

labelsToTransform.forEach(label => transformLabelContainer(label.id, label.imgSrc));
```

Comment: @Cowboy `innerText` is a quirky nonstandard property that IE introduced. It is highly recommended to instead use the standard, quicker, more reliable `textContent` instead - see http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText

Answer (score 0):

To query for the label object you can run

```
let label_payment1 = document.querySelector('.payment-method-wrapper>label[for$=_gateway_1]')
```

Then create the inner node with

```
let img = document.createElement("img")
img.src = "payment-1.jpg"
// .. set other image attributes 
let span = document.createElement("span")  
span.class = "visually-hidden"
let textContent = document.createTextNode("Payment 1"); 
span.appendChild(textContent)
```

And lastly add created nodes to label

```
label_payment1.replaceChild(img,label_payment1.firstChild)
label_payment1.appendChild(span)
```

Edit: This is just a sketch. See @Kevin Huang answer for complete solution.