# How to attach HTML to two similar elements with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two such elements, `gateway_1` and `gateway_13`.

```
<div class="radio__label content-box">
  <label class="radio__label__primary" for="gateway_${id}">
    Test
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like to attach HTML between `</label>` and `</div>`. 
Simplified HTML below:

```
<span class="radio__label__accessory">
 <span style="background-image:url(${imgSrc}),none;">${originalText}</span>
</span>
```

My code is:

```
  function transformLabelContainer(id, imgSrc) {
    const label = document.querySelector(`label[for$=_gateway_${id}]`);
    const originalText = label.innerText;
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'radio__label__accessory';
    span.innerHTML = '<span style="background-image:url(${imgSrc}),none;">${originalText}</span>';
  }

  const labelsToTransform = [
    {
      id: '1',
      imgSrc: 'image.svg'
    },
      id: '13',
      imgSrc: 'image13.svg'
    }
  ];

  labelsToTransform.forEach(label => transformLabelContainer(label.id, label.imgSrc));
```

Hover I can't figure what stopping it from working at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a modification of code from this question: [How to replace two similar HTML elements with vanilla javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829323/how-to-replace-two-similar-html-elements-with-vanilla-javascript/49829886#49829886)

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Your second object literal in `labelsToTransform` is missing a brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

**1-** You need to append the  created `span` to the div:

```
label.parentNode.appendChild(span);
```

**2-** When you set the `innerHTML` of that span, you need to use templating quotes (```) to be able to use `${...}`:

```
span.innerHTML = `<span ...>`;
```

**3-** In your function, you use this selector: `label[for$=_gateway_${id}]` which has an underscore before `gateway`, while this does not seem to be the case in your HTML.

**4-** As Bergi mentioned in the comments, you are missing a curly brace in the `labelsToTransform` constant declaration.

#### Fixed demo

```js
function transformLabelContainer(id, imgSrc) {
  const label = document.querySelector(`label[for$=_gateway_${id}]`);
  const originalText = label.innerText;
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'radio__label__accessory';
  span.innerHTML = `<span style="background-image:url(${imgSrc}),none;">${originalText}</span>`;
  label.parentNode.appendChild(span);
}

const labelsToTransform = [
  { id: '1', imgSrc: 'image.svg' },
  { id: '13', imgSrc: 'image13.svg' }
];

labelsToTransform.forEach(label => transformLabelContainer(label.id, label.imgSrc));
```

```html
<div class="radio__label content-box">
  <label class="radio__label__primary" for="_gateway_1">
    Test
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio__label content-box">
  <label class="radio__label__primary" for="_gateway_13">
    Test
  </label>
</div>
```